# Scrollable list doesn't fits the container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a sidebar with a fixed height (defined by JS) and inside it a div banner and a scrollable list.

The problem is that I want the scrollbar to appear only on the list and I can't use the CSS `calc()` (no IE8 support).

This is the example of the widget and you can clearly see the problem.
The list goes out for the same height of the banner.

```
.sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.banner {
  background: purple;
  height: 50px;  
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/tfgHx

How can I fix this problem without use of JS?

Comment: You might want to use a table structure as you need a remaining height with a unknown header height: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Not exactly semantically correct, tables should be used only to store data.

Comment: No, this is not true. HTML tables should contain "tabular data", this might be because some screen readers look for these elements. But there is no reason the tables should contain data that will be stored. As using the CSS table properties, you can make layouts that are less strict as a HTML table. Else i would like to know why this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign fixed `max-height`  to the list you can because you know the other values:

```
.list {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

The demo **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yetrd**

**Edit**

For dynamic height of the sidebar but Knowing the `height` for the banner what you can do is fake the space of the banner with this properties:

```
.list {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
  border-top:50px solid transparent;
  top:-50px;  
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Faking the space of banner as `border` and `negative top` on the list you secure always that space. And obviusly with `box-sizing:border-box` wich is supported on IE8 check the compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)

And the new demo **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DbFel**

Comment: No the height of the sidebar will be variable (js)

Comment: Ok edit this in your post ... if you are already using JS why you can't use this for the list

Comment: @FezVrasta the height of banner is fixed?? you know the value?

Answer (score 0):

The banner class is a parent and the sidebar class is a child, so it can not over flow it's parent. May be you can do like this, I'm not so sure how your project is. But let try it.

```
.sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.banner {
  background: purple;
  height: 50px;  
  position: relative;
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```